# Datetime trouble when passing value to API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1, datetimeoffset

I working on Angular 6 frontend and .NetCore 2.1 for API

I have trouble when pass datetime value from client to API, my datetime value passed to API it's 
automatically subtracting time to 7 hours, how to keep the server the same value as the sending by client?

I have try add "'Content-Type': 'application/json'" by some topic searchable on google

Answer (score 0):

What is your local timezone saved at? What the is API's timezone set at? I think the fault is at different timezones selected.

Comment: my local timezone is UTC+7 and API Server have same local

Comment: Please share, request-response data and code snapshots.

Comment: here is reponse "2020-04-17T17:00:00.000Z", request look like "Sat Apr 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)"

Comment: You need to parse the date format to the response format  and check if the conversion returns anything else than whats its returning now!